# .NET Core Web API - Proxy HTTP Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API which has to do the following:

Incoming HttpRequest -> Logic to decide which endpoint -> Send call to specific endpoint (another API)
HttpResult -> Logic to manipulate response -> Send response back

I was wondering whether there is a clean way to do so? Currently using something like this:

```
var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    Method = new HttpMethod(Request.Method),
    RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint)
};

using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", Request.Headers["Authorization"][0]);

    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage))
    {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not really happy about the conversion from HttpRequest to HttpRequestMessage. I'd just like to pass the HttpRequest with another Uri but still be able to put logic in between the requesting and receiving.

When working with proxy middleware are you still able to put logic in between the request and result?

Comment: If it's anything like regular Web API you may look into extending the AuthorizeAttribute that you can use to authorize incoming requests and respond to them prior to the request being passed to the corresponding controller. [SessionAuthorize]
    public class BaseController<T> : ApiController

Comment: `HttpClient` is thread safe and is designed to be used as a singleton, if you create a new HttpClient per request [you may end up with `SocketException` errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), also it is not expected of you to dispose of `response.Content`, disposing of `response` [will handle it](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/33ec2994d85935b6c62df0792aef88b285d6c765/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs#L203).